# PHP class and objects

Tags: php, oop

What is the difference between

```
$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = new $obj1;
```

and

```
$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = new Test();
```

Both are creating different memory location for objects.
Does it have any difference...?

Comment: Yes, you can pass construct parameter with direct class call.

Comment: Although there is no difference, you should not reinstantiate this way. In practice, using the first one is only when creating an object on the fly from string, but not from already created object. The practical use could be `$class = 'Test'; $obj = new $class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$obj2 = new $obj1;
```

use like this  `$obj2 = $obj1;`

*you have two variables refering to the same instance of Test.*

but here

```
  $obj1 = new Test();
  $obj2 = new Test();
```

*you have two variables refering to two different instances of Test.*

Comment: In both cases in the question `$obj1` is a different object from `$obj2`.

Comment: Thanks Sajad. 
I just noticed from http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php. 
Would you please explain me the below lines of code in detail 
$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = new $obj1; 
as compared to 
$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = new Test();

Comment: Objects are only equivalent if they both refer to the same instance.

Comment: @simon Are $obj1 and $obj2 the object of same class? And do they have same properties?

Comment: @LekhulalMathalipara:didn't my answer helped ? why the downvote?

Comment: @LekhulalMathalipara They're objects of the same class, but they're different objects. That is, `get_class($obj1) == get_class($obj2)` and `$obj1 != $obj2`.

Answer (score 1):

While there's no functional difference, you probably should try to limit your use of the first one as you have no idea what could be inside `$obj1`.

In both cases, you can then pass arguments and `$obj2` is a separate object from `$obj1` with the same class type.

Confusion with the `new $obj1` format can arise when `Test` has a `__toString` method. In this case, the `__toString` method is not called, even though the usual case for the `new $var()` syntax is when `$var` is a string that has been generated or passed in.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, were you trying to set $obj2 as a reference to $obj1? If so, you should not use the new keyword or it will try to create a new object with a type stored in the $obj1 variable.

Creates two references to the same object:

```
$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = $obj1;//Creates a reference to the first object
```

Comment: No, he is just asking whats the difference